# How can I change all of the data in an observable collection so functions using this can notice the change that happens?

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I have this code:

```
public ObservableCollection<CVM> SObservable{ get; set; }

this.scores = App.DB.GetCardFace(0);
this.SObservable = new ObservableCollection<CVM>(this.scores);
```

I then assign this as a data source:

```
this.columnSeries = new ColumnSeries() {
   ItemsSource = SObservable
};
chart.Series.Add(this.columnSeries);
```

My chart displays correctly

Now I change the data:

```
this.scores = App.DB.GetCardFace(1);
```

but nothing happens to the chart. I suspect the `SObservable` contents are not changing.

Can someone give me advice on how I should go about changing the contents of the `SObservable` so it triggers a change that can be picked up by the chart code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an ObservableCollection does not contain any references to the data that was used to populate it in it's constructor, so a change to that original data will not be reflected in the ObservableCollection

```
SObservable.Clear();

foreach(var s in scores)
{
  SObservable.Add(s);
}
```